# Speech recognition and translation

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I have a functioning speech-to-text app and i would like to implement "speech-to-translated-text" so when a user speaks in a specific language it is getting translated to English and displayed as text instead of the original speech-to-text input that is currently displayed. So we need to modify this code to do that if at all possible...

```
final EditText resultText = findViewById(R.id.resultText);

//Creating and setting up the SpeechRecognizer
final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float v) {}

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {}

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {}

    @Override
    public void onError(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
        //Getting matches
        ArrayList<String> matches = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        if (matches != null) {
            //Displaying the first match
            resultText.setText(resultText.getText() + " " + matches.get(0));
            resultText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            resultText.setSelection(resultText.getText().length());
            while (resultText.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                resultText.scrollBy(0, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {}

});
```

speechBtn:

```
//Setting up speechBtn states
findViewById(R.id.speechBtn).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

            //User stops touching the button.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                break;

            //User touches the button.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                try {
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    //In case speech is not supported
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support Speech Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I tried to find something similar being done before but i wasn't in luck and i have no clue on how to proceed.

Comment: Translation is not built into the Android framework.  You'll need to find a 3rd party library that supports it (and likely need to pay for it).  Also, expect the results to be pretty bad, as machine translation of short messages tends to be poor.

Comment: Well yeah i wouldn't be expecting accurate translation anyway...

Comment: I know that Google Translate has an API (I've used it), but it isn't cheap.

Comment: Link me some info to check it out.